# Which event to fire on tab key press to save the data

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

Current I am using simple windows forms with VB.net. It has dynamically created datetime picker. I have placed one save button on form. But now I want to get rid of that save button and when I tab off on datetime picker should save data automatically firing some event on tab off. Which event should be used to fire tab key press, Upon tab key press i want to save my data.

My form looks like this.

[image]

My Save button logic

```
Private Sub UltraButtonSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UltraButtonSave.Click
    If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("ConveyanceID")) AndAlso Not DBNull.Value.Equals(chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("TripID")) Then
        Modal.ARG_ConveyanceID = chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("ConveyanceID")
        Modal.ARG_TripID = chkdtDataTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("TripID")
        Modal.ARG_NumberOfConveyance = UltraNumberOfConveyance.Value
        Dim prevDatevalue As Object = Nothing
        For Each o As Object In UltraPanel1.ClientArea.Controls
            If TypeOf (o) Is UltraDateTimeEditor Then
                Dim datePicker As UltraDateTimeEditor = o

                If prevDatevalue <> Nothing AndAlso datePicker.Value <> Nothing Then
                    If datePicker.Value < prevDatevalue Then
                        ' Do something Previous value is Lesser
                        lblSuccess.Text = "Please verify date entered."
                        lblSuccess.ForeColor = Color.Red
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
                Modal.ARG_CheckPointTimeID = Convert.ToInt32(datePicker.Tag.Split(","c)(0))
                Modal.ARG_TerminalCheckPointID = Convert.ToInt32(datePicker.Tag.Split(","c)(1))
                Modal.ARG_CheckPointTimeValue = datePicker.Value
                Helper.InsertCheckPointTimesScreen(Modal)
                Helper.GetCheckPointTimes(Modal)
                prevDatevalue = datePicker.Value
                lblSuccess.Text = "Data Saved Successfully."
                lblSuccess.ForeColor = Color.Green
            End If
        Next
    Else
        lblSuccess.Text = "Selected Order does not have Trip/Conveyance created."
        lblSuccess.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a Control.Leave event that is triggered everytime your current control loses the focus. You can subscribe to this event when you dinamically create the DateTimePickers

Comment: @Steve Leave event is fired twice. How to fix it

Comment: Add your modified code.